# Why do I got "You did not select a file to upload." error message when I did it?

Tags: forms, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I have a very similar code where it works fine, but here I got an error message. I would like a form where there is an input field. On submit is I would like to save the file. However, when I choose a file, it gives me this error message. To test it, I set the `required` attribute to the input field and this way the form let me submit it, so I do not understand why I got this message. Do you have any idea?

**The form:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="update-car-form" class="needs-validation" action="<?= base_url(); ?>test/updateCar">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="carID" id="carID" required>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <div class="avatar-upload">
                <div class="avatar-edit">
                    <input type='file' name="updateIndex" id="indexImageUpdate" accept=".png" />
                    <label class="text-center" for="indexImageUpdate"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="avatar-preview">
                    <div id="updateIndexImage" style="background-image: url(<?= base_url() ?>img/image_holders/car-front.png)">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><?= $this->lang->line('close') ?></button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="update-car-form"><?= $this->lang->line('save') ?></button>
</div>
```

**The code:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['updateIndex']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['updateIndex']['name'])) {
    $plate_number = $this->input->post('updatePlateNumber');
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
    $config['upload_path'] = './img/cars/';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = $plate_number;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('updateIndex')) { 
        $this->resize($this->upload->data(), 960, 540);
    }
    else {
        $succesful = false;
        print_r(0);
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
        die;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form tag.  It must be present to upload an image.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" id="update-car-form" class="needs-validation" action="<?= base_url(); ?>test/updateCar">
```

As per [Official documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

**enctype**

> If the value of the `method` attribute is `post`, enctype is the `MIME` type of the form submission. Possible values:
>
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: The default value.
>
> **`multipart/form-data`: Use this if the form contains `<input>` elements with `type=file`.**
>
> `text/plain`: Introduced by HTML5 for debugging purposes.

Comment: You are right, I missed it, but unfortunately not that caused the problem. I still got this: "You did not select a file to upload." message.